# Use Mat-Paginator inside child component, when Mat-Table is inside Parent Component

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use the mat-paginator inside a child component. The mat-paginator should change the data of a mat-table. The mat-table is inside the parent component.

parent.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">....columns...</table>
<app-child [dataSource]="dataSource" [paginator]="paginator" [sort]="sort"></app-child>
```

parent.ts

```
@Input() dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;
@ViewChild('paginator') paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;
ngOnInit(): void {
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
ngAfterContentChecked(){
this.ref.detectChanges();
}
```

child.ts

```
template: `
<mat-paginator #paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 50, 100]"></mat-paginator>
`

...

@Input() paginator: MatPaginator;
@Input() sort!: MatSort
@Input() dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

When looking at the paginator i only see 0 of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There several solutions to solve the question:

1.-Always you have a "child component", using a template reference variable you have access to all the public properties (by defect variables, functions, ViewChild,etc are public)

You have in parent:

```
@ViewChild('child') child!:ChildComponent;
//you can use also
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child!:ChildComponent;

<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">....columns...</table>
<app-child #child></app-child>
```

In app-child you have the typical

```
//paginator is a mat-paginator of the child
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
```

Now you can assign the paginator in parent.ts like

```
this.dataSource.paginator = this.child.paginator;
```

2.-Another option is pass the dataSource as input to the child in a setter, and assign in it the mat-paginator

```
//In child
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;

@Input() dataSource set _data(value:MatDataSource<any>){
    //see that the only you do is assign the paginator
    this.value.paginator=this.paginator
}
```

in your parent

```
<app-child [dataSource]="dataSource"></app-child>
```

See that, when you pass using an Input a complex object, you pass the reference (the own object, not a copy)

Comment: Thank you, this works. I assigned the paginator inside the child.ts, but this works too. Thank you!